# OID's and MIB's for CISCO, JUNIPER and ZTE Router/ Switch devices

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp, oid, mib

I want OID's and MIB's for CISCO, JUNIPER and ZTE Router/ Switch devices to monitor CM, PM & FM datas through SNMP. So Please kindly share me the details.

Also If you share dumps/files/logs related to it much appreciated.

Comment: It is very unclear what exact problem you are running into while working with snmp. May I kindly suggest you start off by reading the MIB reference and snmp documentation for each of the products?

Comment: Hi,
             For ZTE MIB's i tried in www.OIDview.com but when i try to use it, then it shows MIB is not supported. So if you give me any other link to download MIB for ZTE devices that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First hit on google for each:

- Cisco MIB's: http://www.cisco.com/public/sw-center/netmgmt/cmtk/mibs.shtml
- Juniper MIB's: http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/index_mibs.html
- ZTE MIB's: http://www.oidview.com/mibs/3902/md-3902-1.html

Now go hang your head in shame :)

Comment: Hi Dennis,
             For ZTE MIB's i tried in www.OIDview.com but when i try to use it, then it shows MIB is not supported. So if you give me any other link to download MIB for ZTE devices that will be helpful.